# Use and relate multiple databases

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, multiple-databases

I can't seem to find a good answer to this. What is the correct way in SQLAlchemy (declarative) to connect two SQLite databases? I also need to make a relation between two tables in these two seperate databases.

**Edit:**
It is some sort of commenting system. I already have a database with data (posts) and I'm now building a social Flask webapplication around it where users can register and comment on these posts.
Preferably, I would like to keep the code for the posts database as unchanged as possible so I can use the same code for the web and desktop application.

This is how it looks basicly:

```
database1 (created and controlled by flask-sqlalchemy):
  - users
  - comments

database2 (created and controlled by SQLAlchemy):
  - posts
```

Comment: Do two databases contain different tables, or the same tables?

Comment: I updated my question, hopefully it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the documentation for [Simple Vertical Partitioning](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#simple-vertical-partitioning), quote from there:

> Vertical partitioning places different kinds of objects, or different
>   tables, across multiple databases:

```
engine1 = create_engine('postgresql://db1')
engine2 = create_engine('postgresql://db2')

Session = sessionmaker(twophase=True)

# bind User operations to engine 1, Account operations to engine 2
Session.configure(binds={User:engine1, Account:engine2})

session = Session()
```

Also read the answer inside of the question [SQLAlchemy Declarative + relationships across multiple different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7410010/99594), which will give you more sample code to start with